# Custom slot label in timeline view depending on days count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I need to add custom label depending on day count.
For example, I have 1 calendar year

```js
defaultView: 'timeline12Month',
views: {
  timeline12Month: {
    type: 'timeline',
    duration: {
      week: 52
    },
    titleFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
  }
}
```

So I need to add custom label depending on custom day count. For example, I need to add multiple stages. Stage 1(20 days), Stage 2(55 days), Stage 3(150 days) and so on.
I know its possible to change monthName array, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Is this possible to do in fullcalendar(scheduler)?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo

Comment: no, this is custom duration. i need custom labels above the calendar days. http://prntscr.com/j8l15c Instead of stage 2, there should be for example 10 days(112-122), growth stage, + 10 days (122-132) harvest stage and so on

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with fullCalendar (I deal with it years ago) but I do want to help. If you could create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) I will try to modify it to solve your problem..

Comment: @MoshFeu https://codepen.io/ganya/pen/aGvYyY

Comment: So, as much as I understand that you can't use the months labels because the days are not compatible to month days (e.g. 10 days but not the whole month) right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Sorry, then. I don't know if it possible..

Comment: I think you would have to customise the source code of the view to achieve this